# Files not seen by Finder

Tags: terminal, finder, mojave

I seem to have a weird issue with a Photo editing tool called [Lumniar 3](https://skylum.com/luminar). Though I have this issue with this software, I tend to think that it could be a file setting that Finder is acting on.

The issue is, when I use the export functionality in this software to create a JPEG file from a RAW file, Finder never sees that file. I can `ls` the file though and can see them via Terminal.app.

I am using a mid 2015 15" MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.1.

I have posted the question on their software support forum as well.

Comment: I also have Luminar 3, but I don't have this issue with exporting raw files (.nef, .cr2, .pef) to jpeg: they do appear normally in the Finder. (I'm also using a MacBook Pro 2015 with Mojave)

Comment: If you run `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` and relaunch Finder, do the files show up?

Comment: @JMY1000 Before attempting your suggestion, I actually restarted my machine. Post that, the files do show up in Finder. However, I'm unable to upload them to sites like 500px, SmugMug etc. I'm hoping that this is a browser specific or some kind of restriction in my machine.